# Lack of color displaying composite video

Tags: video, ntsc

I'm attempting to output video from a TMS9118 VDP to a television's composite video port.  Right now the result I'm getting is grey scale (whereas the background should be green), and I have no idea why.  I have compared the output from the TMS9118 comvid line to output from a DVD player on my oscilloscope, and the signals are somewhat different in quality.[image: compared signals]

The yellow signal is the dvd player.  The blue signal is the VDP.

Following is what the VDP produces on the television screen:

[image]

The TV displays the DVD player signal perfectly.  In summary, what is wrong with the signal coming out of the TMS9118 comvid line?

Comment: Are you sure you mean composite video? It looks to me like component video. Composite video has one 75 ohm cable, while component video has three.

Comment: Something's very wrong here. There's no way you should be measuring a >100V signal out of the DVD player. More likely you have a grounding problem.

Comment: Mark, yes it is composite video.  There's only one video output on the 9118.  Other versions do support component, but not this one.

Comment: duskwuff, you are quite correct.  I fixed the grounding and now the voltage is similar to the signal from the VDP.  Also it looks a lot cleaner than the signal from the VDP.

Comment: Is your colorburst frequency correct for your monitor?

Comment: It is way too noisy. Notice on the DVD trace how the color burst is cleanly sitting on the porch. Both porches and the horizontal sync are clear and flat. Notice on the bottom trace how you can barely make them out in the noise. I'm surprised it displays at all, but can understand why the TV might not recognize the color burst.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Hmm I"m not sure.  I thought the monitor was supposed to detect the colorburst and then interpret the signal appropriately.

Comment: @Mark Thanks.  I'm gonna try this with a try this with an actual lab regulated power supply instead of my crappy noisy custom made junk.

Comment: @Mark Do you think a low pass filter might help reduce the noise on the signal coming out of the VDP?  I replaced my custom power supply with a very clean bench supply with no resulting reduction in noise.

Comment: Adam, if you are running NTSC, then the color-burst is around 3.58MHz, so the low-pass filter would need to be near 4MHz. That may not help much. Do you have another TMS9118 chip? have you looked at power and ground at the chip? Could a pin on the TMS9118 be shorted?

Comment: @Mark thanks again for the great pointer.  Avg. Vpk - Vpk is 1V at power and ground on the TMS9118.  Is that pretty bad?

Comment: [This is what an NTSC composite video signal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MhbC_YgKvNU) should look like. That first, fast "blip" is the color information, which is almost completely drowned by noise. [More info](http://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1272387) here.

Comment: Some progress, @Mark et. al. I tried completely disconnecting the RCA cable from the VDP and found that the signal became *significantly* cleaner, though I don't know if clean enough.  Going to try a shorter cable next.

Comment: do you have the correct 75Ohm termination on your source end?

Comment: Please include a schematic in your question. Show all components associated with the NTSC output and power supply (e.g. bypass capacitors). A photo of your BB would help too.

Answer (score 1):

It  would appear that you have significant ground current noise between the two systems or some other large CM noise.

The VDP scale is 1/4 of the DVD yellow scale to see that same size sync tip and chroma burst. The amplitude must be double amplitude for a 75Ohm source and load and the same as the DVD player.

The output level for chroma sync if too low or noisy would disable chroma video from being displayed in the VDT.

The VDT shows a LOT of pixel clock noise on the display.

Shields up and improve grounds.